# How to mix fluid and fixed widths?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have 2 boxes side-by-side. I want the width of the left box to be fixed, while the right box is fluid, filling the remaining browser width.

The following is my best attempt (which is so wrong):

```
<body style="font-size:0">
  <div style="100%;border:3px solid black">
    <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:red;width:50px;height:50px"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;background-color:green;width:100%;height:50px"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a link: https://plnkr.co/edit/5Mx41Her7bOr1dy99f7R?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *table layout* - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  background-color: green;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Or better still, you can use a `flexbox`:

1. Set `display: flex` the `wrapper`
2. Add `flex: 1` to the *fluid* item

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}
.wrapper div:last-child {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your example your are using bootstrap framework, so you can use the bootstrap grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">First box</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">Second box</div>
</div>
```

Else, with CSS, you can use Flexbox like that :

```css
.container-box {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.container-box .left-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.container-box .right-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="left-box"></div>
  <div class="right-box"></div>
</div>
```